# Check Style Table with watir

Tags: css, html-table, each, watir

I'm having problems extracting style tables to use watir with .style method

I have a structure in the web like this:

```
.
.
.
<div class="content-global-div">
   <table class="content-global-table content-global-bg">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td style="vertical-aling:top;padding:25px 40px;">
               <div class="content-global-title">...</div>
               <div class="content-global-title">...</div>
               <div class="content-global-box">
                  <div style="...">...</div>
                  <table cellspacing="0">
                     <tbody>
                        <tr></tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td style="padding:10px;">
                              <table class="blocos" style="background:#f2f2f2;opacity:0.7;border:1px solid #eee;cursor:default;"></table>
                              <table class="blocos" style="background:#f2f2f2;opacity:0.7;border:1px solid #eee;cursor:default;"></table>
                              <table class="blocos" style=""></table>
                              <table class="blocos" style=""></table>
                              .
                              .
                              .
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                     </tbody>
                  </table>
               </div>
               <div class="content-global-box">
                  <div style="...">...</div>
                  <table cellspacing="0">
                     <tbody>
                        <tr></tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td style="padding:10px;">
                              <table class="blocos" style="background:#f2f2f2;opacity:0.7;border:1px solid #eee;cursor:default;"></table>
                              <table class="blocos" style="background:#f2f2f2;opacity:0.7;border:1px solid #eee;cursor:default;"></table>
                              <table class="blocos" style=""></table>
                              <table class="blocos" style=""></table>
                              .
                              .
                              .
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                     </tbody>
                  </table>
               </div>
               <div class="content-global-box">
                  <div style="...">...</div>
                  <table cellspacing="0">
                     <tbody>
                        <tr></tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td style="padding:10px;">
                              <table class="blocos" style="background:#f2f2f2;opacity:0.7;border:1px solid #eee;cursor:default;"></table>
                              <table class="blocos" style="background:#f2f2f2;opacity:0.7;border:1px solid #eee;cursor:default;"></table>
                              <table class="blocos" style=""></table>
                              <table class="blocos" style=""></table>
                              .
                              .
                              .
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                     </tbody>
                  </table>
               </div>
               .
               .
               .
```

What I need to do is to put myself in each class tables: blocos and specifically visualize the opacity style, now what I have is the following:

```
tbl = browser.div(:class => 'content-global-box').table.tbody.tr

tbl.tds.each do |td|

    puts td.style.to_s()

end
```

but has not given me results and I'm not sure that's what I'm
need,
someone could be so kind to explain how to do it?

Comment: `browser.div(:class => 'content-global-box').table.tbody.tr` returns the first row of the first table in a div with a class attribute of 'content-global-box'.  That row is empty: `<tr></tr>`

Comment: So what I should do is this:                                      browser.div(:class => 'content-global-box').table.tbody.tr[1] ?

Comment: That would return a table cell containing 4 tables.  Something like this should print the `.style` attribute for each table with a class attribute of 'content-global-box': `b.div(:class => 'content-global-box').tables(:class=>"blocos").each { |table| puts table.style}`

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding the question, but this will print the `.style` value for each table with a class of "blocos" contained in each div with a class of "content-global-box":

```
b.divs(:class => 'content-global-box').each do |div|
  div.tables(:class=>"blocos").each do |table|
    puts table.style
  end
end
```

Comment: `.style` will return the attribute value - eg "background:#f2f2f2;opacity:0.7;border:1px solid #eee;cursor:default;". If the goal is to check the opacity, perhaps `.style('opacity')` would be useful. It has the benefit of getting the computed style as well saving the manual parsing of the style attribute.

Comment: @Justin Ko: +1.  I missed that requirement.  And here's a link to the [`.style`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Element#style-instance_method) method documentation.